# Replace HTML Quotes with Plain Text in XSLT

Tags: html, xslt

We are using XSLT to translate a RIXML file to XML.  Our RIXML contains the following text:

```
<Title><![CDATA[Looking into the future: Reiterate &#8216;Buy&#8217;]]></Title>
```

8216 is a left quote and 8217 is a right quote.

How would I replace these HTML codes with their plain text representation, or more simply, just a single quote?  This is XSLT version 1.0.

Comment: It's not clear why you are using CDATA sections. Those character references are allowed in XML. Also, the accepted answer won't work with your input sample as is.

Comment: We are receiving this XML from a third party source.  It was my understanding that it was incorrect also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vQ2">""</xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:value-of select=
   "translate(.,'&#8216;&#8217;',$vQ2)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: In my particular implementation I needed to escape the Ampersands thusly: <xsl:value-of select="translate(node, '&amp;#8216;&amp;#8217;', $vQ2)"/>

Comment: @frinkenstein789: that's weird. If you had to double-escape, you're doing something peculiar that you haven't told us about. However, neither the provided solution nor your double-escaped version should work if the input as as supplied, with a CDATA section, because &#8216; in a CDATA section represents 7 characters, not one.

Comment: @Michael-Kay: Yes, in this case the `replace()` function (XPath 2.0) or a recursive named template should be used. I thought the OP had only accidentally used CDATA.

Answer (score 0):

I came upon this function which worked well for me.  I call it to replace all the characters I need to:

```
<xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
  <xsl:param name="text" />
  <xsl:param name="replace" />
  <xsl:param name="by" />
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)" />
      <xsl:value-of select="$by" />
      <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
        <xsl:with-param name="text"
        select="substring-after($text,$replace)" />
        <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
        <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```